# Facebook profile login time-stamp

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can we fetch the user last login timestamp using graph-api or FQL? please suggest any idea to fetch acount login activity.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. See the listing of available `user` object fields at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user#fields

Comment: What i should Do still if i needed that information please can you suggest.

Comment: Sorry, but do you understand the meaning of *it is not possible*?

Comment: Yeh i am sorry for that, but i am just asking is there any alternative way to do so